# Formal definition of non deterministic PDA

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

How would you convert the following formal definition of deterministic pushdown automata into non deterministic ?

> Deterministic PDAs In general terms, a deterministic PDA is one in
> which there is at most one possible transition from any state based on
> the current input. Formally, a deterministic PDA is a PDA where:
>
> for every state $P$, input symbol $\hbox{'}{a}\hbox{'}$ and stack
> symbol $t$, there is at most one transition of the form
> $(P,a,t)\mapsto(Q,u)$ for any state $Q$ and stack symbol $u$. Any
> context-free language that can be converted to a deterministic PDA is
> called a deterministic CFL.

Comment: Under heavy pressure or for a comfortable fee, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you would convert the definition of deterministic finite automata to a nondeterministic one:

The transition function would output a **set** of transitions instead of a single one.

This means that if in the deterministic case we have $\delta(p,a,t)=(q,u)$, now it will look like: $\delta(p,a,t)=\{(q_1,u_1),...,(q_n,u_n)\}$ for any $q_i,u_i$ we choose.

Formally, the transition function is $\delta:Q\times\Sigma\times\Gamma\rightarrow P(Q\times\Gamma)$ where $Q$ are the states, $\Sigma$ are the input symbols, and $\Gamma$ are the stack symbols

Comment: I did understand  $(p,a,t)=\{(q1, u1), (q2, u2)... \}$ but still not getting how would this $(P,a,t)\mapsto(Q,u)$ be converted to non deterministic ?

Comment: If you want a non-deterministic version of a deterministic PDA, you will get that $\delta(p,a,t)$ is a singleton

Comment: Can i write its deterministic version as this: $(P,a,t)\mapsto(2^{(Q,u)})$